# Aframe 360 image within Carousel

Tags: javascript, aframe

I need help. I'm trying to add a 360 image to a carousel using aframe but there is little to no documentation about it. Currently, the `<a-scene>` works perfectly fine when placed within the page, but when added to the carousel I get `core:a-node:error Failure loading node:   TypeError: can't access property "constructor", e is undefined`. I've tried adding timeouts, delay's and nothing seems to work.

Here is a codepen with a similar situation: https://codepen.io/RobLessard/pen/jOqJBwg

Comment: It seems to work when it isn't the first image in the slider. so something isn't rendering correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work, it just renders the title of the page not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/RobLessard/pen/jOqJBwg) is not importing A-Frame properly (in the `<head>` tag). Click on the HTML gear icon and make sure A-Frame is imported in the `<head>`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am now.. Still nothing

Comment: Not familiarized with your carousel library. It seems it's moving elements around? FWIW, your scene renders after ddding A-Frame to the header and removing the carousel initialization. https://codepen.io/dmarcos/pen/poyYPGp I would try to understand how your carousel work and / or give alternatives a try.